# Parse webpage through VBA with Chrome

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome

I want to extract information from a website with VBA and using Chrome instead of Internet Explorer. I have manage to open the page from VBA but what I am struggling with is how to refer to the open webpage.

So for Internet Explorer I had:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate (s1.Cells(x, 1))
key = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("...").Innertext
```

Now I want to replicate this but in Chrome. I managed to do this:

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & s1.Cells(x, 1))
```

but I don`t know how to move forward.

Comment: Chrome doesn't provide the same kind of COM interface for automation that IE does.  You could try looking at Selenium: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/